# AWS Pricing VS Google-Cloud-Platform Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I want to host my website (PHP/MySQL) on a cloud platform. For sure, my website is new and I don't think that there will be too much traffic. 
So, I tried to compare the lowest config costs of cloud services between GCP and AWS. The lowest config cost according [Google Cloud Platform pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/?hl=fr) is as follows:

- Google Compute Engine (f1-micro): $4.09
- Google Cloud SQL (D0 Instance): $11.30
- Datastore (1GB): $0.18
- **Total**: $15.57
  (For details, have a look on this link: https://goo.gl/wJZikT )

Meanwhile, the lowest config cost according [AWS Pricing calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) is:

- Amazon EC2 (t1.micro): $14.64
- Amazon RDS (db.t1.micro with 1GB of storage): $18.42
- Amazon S3: $0.11
- **Total**: $33.17

(For details, have a look on this link http://goo.gl/Pe7dFt )

My question is: how can it be that there is a big difference in the cost of cloud services between google cloud platform and AWS? Is there any thing wrong in my estimation? If it is the case please share with me a link on the configuration of the minimal configuration on AWS...

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your estimations .....

Comment: Really!!! So why there many websites are hosted in AWS?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-Compute-Engine-compare-to-AWS

Comment: So you advise me to go for Google cloud platform?

Comment: I'm not AWS expert, so I cannot compare your pricings. However, for the Google Cloud pricing you're missing the Persistent disk storage in your estimation which will add $0.40 for 10GB. Also, Google Cloud Datastore is a NoSQL database for storing non-relational data. Amazon S3 pricing should be compared with Google Cloud Storage. In the following link you will find some pricing examples for the Google Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

Comment: Also you are comparing REALLY tiny servers, which doesn't make sense for anything other than a low traffic person site.  This price comparison has no bearing on what a real, commercial site would pay on Google Cloud or AWS.

Comment: And this what I have done...

Comment: There is a free tier of AWS: http://aws.amazon.com/free/. Also I think  what @IanRose was saying is that there is a relatively big price difference at such a low tier, but this is not the tier most people are paying for. When you asked why there are so many sites hosted on AWS, surely part of the answer could be that their higher tiers are cheaper than google's. It's also a point to make that AWS took the scene by storm, being the first to become popular in offering this business model.

Comment: @papergodzilla: nice point of view. I guess a comparison for bigger servers should be made...

Comment: And you can get 100GB of data storage plus Mysql from Godaddy for  $5.99 per month.  That does not mean it is the correct solution for all products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 main reasons for the difference:

1. Google micro VM uses a shared core and not a dedicated one. Cores seem to be the most expensive part of a VM if you look at prices for both AWS an GCE
2. Google provide their sustained usage discount on a monthly basis (30% effective discount per month), while amazon forces you to commit for a year with upfront payment to get any discount.

Both factors above allow you to have a lower cost for the Google VM.

I have tried VMs on GCE with shared cores and did not have any problems. If you use Google monitoring, you can actually track how much the core being shared is affecting you using the CPU steal metric. This article from [stackdriver](http://www.stackdriver.com/understanding-cpu-steal-experiment/) explain it really well.

Side note: stackdriver has been since acquired by Google and is what Google use for monitoring the VMs.